# Does $f(x)$ converge when $x$ goes to infinity if $f'(x)$ goes to $0$ when $x$ goes to infinity?

Tags: calculus, limits, derivatives

Clarification:
Does $\lim\limits_{x \to \infty}f'(x)=0$ as $x$ approaches infinity  mean $\lim\limits_{x \to \infty} f(x)$ exists in the extended real numbers $[-\infty,\infty]$?

I was thinking a lot about this problem and I couldn't 
prove it; I would appreciate any help!

This isn't a duplicate! In that problem you have to prove that the limit of f(x) exists in the extended real numbers, you don't assume it does.

Comment: You can get any behavior at infinity combined with any behavior at zero.  If you really do mean limits at $\infty$ and at $0$.

Comment: No, the thing is that in that problem you need to prove that the limit of f(x) exists (including infinity)

Comment: @Tamir The limit of $f(x)$ as $x$ goes to what? did you mean to ask about $\lim_{x\to\infty}$ or $\lim_{x\to0}$?

Comment: as x approaches infinity

Comment: Does anyone have any idea?

Answer (score 4):

No, there is a simple counter example. $$f'(x)=\frac1x\implies \lim_{x\to\infty}f'(x)=0$$ But $$f(x)=\log x, \lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)=\infty$$

Comment: he asked about $\lim \limits_{x \to 0} f(x)$, furthermore he asks what is the general behavior.

Comment: @Ahmad Hmm, I am sure he must have meant $\infty$, especially after reading the title. If he did mean $x\to0$, then you could take $f(x)=\frac1x$ to get infinite behaviour at $0$, and something like $f(x)=e^{-x}$ to get finite behaviour. But as mentioned in the comment on the question, you can combine functions to get any behaviour at $0$, regardless of what happens at $\infty$

Comment: Please read again the problem, somewhy someone edited it wrongly...

Comment: @Tamir I answered your question with $x\to\infty$. My comment referred to $x\to 0$.

Comment: where did you answer it with x goes to infinity?

Comment: @Tamir I gave you an example of a function $f(x)$ whose derivative goes to $0$ as $x\to\infty$, but where the actual function $f(x)$ does not converge to a finite value - it goes to infinity.

Comment: right, but I want to prove that f(x) converges to a finite or infinite value!

Comment: @Tamir My answer shows that $f(x)$ could be infinite as $x\to\infty$. There are many different examples where $f(x)$ could converge to any finite value. e.g. $f(x)=\frac1x+a$ converges to any finite value $a$ that you want it to.

Comment: @John Doe Tamir wants to know if the limit exists in general (including possibly $\pm \infty$).  See my edit of the question.